# Pandas KeyError: Predictions not in index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code,

```
train = data[:training_data_len]
valid = data[training_data_len:]
valid ['Prediction'] = predictions
plt.figure(figsize = (16,8))
plt.title('Model')
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Close Price USD ($)', fontsize=18)
plt.plot(train['Close'])
plt.plot(valid[['Close', 'Predictions']])
plt.legend(['Train','Val', 'Predictions'], loc= 'lower right')
plt.show()
```

I'll get the following error:

```
KeyError: "['Predictions'] not in index"
```

It seems to have a very easy fix, but I'm just too new to Python to know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you include the entire traceback? In particular, the line number which causes the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a little vague so if you could tell us which line is throwing the error you might get better responses. But based on what you wrote here, I noticed that you named the field in the `valid` dataframe 'Prediction' (singular) and later in the code you start referring to 'Predictions' (plural). Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).